# Unable to create foreign-key relationship with gorm where field name != type name

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm trying to create a "belongs-to" relationship in my application where the name of the field (and db column) is not the same as the type name. Gorm is complaining about this. Here is a short example that demonstrates the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

type Car struct {
    gorm.Model
    Owner   User
    OwnerID int
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
}

func main() {
    db, _ := gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db")
    defer db.Close()
    db.LogMode(true)

    db.CreateTable(&Car{}, &User{})

    u := User{}
    u.ID = 1
    db.Create(&u)

    c := Car{}
    c.ID = 1
    c.Owner = u
    db.Create(&c)

    cars := make([]Car, 5)
    db.Find(&cars)
    for i := range cars {
        db.Model(cars[i]).Related(&cars[i].Owner)
    }

    for i := range cars {
        fmt.Println(cars[i].Owner.ID)
    }
}
```

We would expect this program to print out "1" as its last line, as this is the primary key of the Users relation that "owns" the only car in the database. Instead "0" is printed out, and verbose logging shows an error at the `Related(&cars[i].Owner)` step:

```
(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:26)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [122.35ms]  CREATE TABLE "cars" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement,"created_at" datetime,"updated_at" datetime,"deleted_at" datetime,"owner_id" integer )

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:26)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [98.96ms]  CREATE INDEX idx_cars_deleted_at ON "cars"(deleted_at)

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:26)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [108.95ms]  CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer primary key autoincrement,"created_at" datetime,"updated_at" datetime,"deleted_at" datetime )

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:26)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [125.74ms]  CREATE INDEX idx_users_deleted_at ON "users"(deleted_at)

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:30)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [0.53ms]  INSERT INTO "users" ("id","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at") VALUES ('1','2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00','2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00','<nil>')

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:35)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [1.98ms]  UPDATE "users" SET "created_at" = '2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00', "updated_at" = '2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00', "deleted_at" = '<nil>'  WHERE "users".deleted_at IS NULL AND "users"."id" = '1'

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:35)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [0.43ms]  INSERT INTO "cars" ("id","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","owner_id") VALUES ('1','2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00','2016-04-09T19:33:46-04:00','<nil>','1')

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:38)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  [0.64ms]  SELECT * FROM "cars"  WHERE "cars".deleted_at IS NULL

(/home/nate/gocode/src/foo/main.go:40)
[2016-04-09 19:33:46]  invalid association []
0
```

What is going on here? Is there some special tag that I have to use on the `Owner` field? I've tried using `gorm:"ForeignKey:owner_id"` and `gorm:"AssociationForeignKey:owner_id"`, both giving the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way in your case is specify foreign field name. So your

```
db.Model(cars[i]).Related(&cars[i].Owner)
```

should be like

```
db.Model(cars[i]).Related(&cars[i].Owner, "Owner")
```

Alternative ways are

- Rename `Owner` and `OwnerID` fields to `User` and `UserID` or
- Rename `User` structure to `Owner`

In these cases GORM will select right foreign keys automatically. From [GORM documentation about associations](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/associations.html#has-one):

> If the field name is same as the variable's type name it could be omitted.

Comment: There's really no automatic way to do this with tags, I have to specify the key every time?

Comment: @NateMara https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/blob/master/scope.go#L962 I see only one way to automate it - name your fields after submodel.